# Float.parseFloat throwing numberformat exception while Float.valueOf working fine

Tags: java, android

I am passing 3.5 value to glb_value

```
         float sendValueFloat = Float.valueOf(glb_value);
```

above is working fine

```
         float sendValueFloat = Float.parseFloat(glb_value);
```

but above is throwing numberformat exception

can anybody explain me why

Comment: did you check what you want with hardcoding 3.5 to see if the problem resolves ?

Comment: Can you not check implementation of both methods?

Comment: Just to ask the stupid question: are you passing 3.5 or "3.5"? (I'm guessing you're passing it as a string, or the second case would probably not even compile).

Comment: Where was the problem in your code? Did it have to do with glb_value?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the implementation of `Float.valueOf(String)` in Java 8:

```
public static Float valueOf(String s) throws NumberFormatException {
    return new Float(parseFloat(s));
}
```

As you can see, `valueOf` calls `parseFloat` to parse the string argument.  It is not possible that `valueOf` works and `parseFloat` doesn't ... if you are passing the same string to each one.

Therefore you must be passing different strings.  Take a look at your evidence again.

If this doesn't help, then run your application with a debugger, set a breakpoint and single-step through the `parseFloat` call to see why it is failing.

Answer (score 0):

**parseFloat()** method(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#parseFloat(java.lang.String)) :-

> Returns a new float initialized to the value represented by the
>   specified String, as performed by the valueOf method of class Float.
>
> Returns: the float value represented by the string argument.

parse method takes string as arguement and convert it into Float object and returns it.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#valueOf(float)

**valueOf**(float f) and **valueOf**(String s):-
Whereas valueOf is used to convert primitive datatype float or string arguement to wrapper class Float. It takes float/string as input and returns Float class object.

ParseFloat(String s) is equal to valueOf(String s) both returns Float object taking string as input. Only difference is valueOf() method has two overloaded method, one takes float and another takes String. First is used to convert primitive datatype to wrapper class while another is equal to valueOf(String s)

Answer (score 0):

there is no error in what you want to do. I think you must debug your `glb_value` before sending to both of these functions.

look at below I tested what you want to do and everything is ok:
[ideOne](http://ideone.com/EJKn8O)

the only different between these two is `Float.parseFloat()` returns a primitive float while the other one returns an object from Float class.

Answer (score 0):

I find this impossible as both function use **FloatingDecimal.parseFloat(s);**

I suggest you look into stack trace and dump of the input value as bytes. Perhaps you encounter problem with encoding or the value you think you parse is not the one you think.

These are the two functions you mention:

```
//1:
public static float parseFloat(String s) throws NumberFormatException {
    return FloatingDecimal.parseFloat(s);
}
//2:
public static Float valueOf(String s) throws NumberFormatException {
    return new Float(parseFloat(s));
}
```

The first one calls directly: `FloatingDecimal.parseFloat(s);` 
The second one has call `{ new Float(parseFloat(s)); };`

```
public Float(float value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public static float parseFloat(String s) throws NumberFormatException {
    return FloatingDecimal.parseFloat(s);
}
```

Both functions end-up calling the same `FloatingDecimal.parseFloat(s);`